# Event Hub Checkpoint Data is Not Saved

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am running the event hub receiver implementation from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events and I haven't changed anything except the connection strings etc.

After creating hundreds of events, I can see that the receiver created checkpoint folder inside the storage account, but as I run the receiver again I see that it processes the same events.

The files that are created per partitions also are empty.

The storage is provided in the consumerClient:

```
checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string("...", "eventhubcontainer")


client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string("...", consumer_group="$Default", eventhub_name="eventhub1", checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)
```

Also after reading the event there is method saving the checkpoint:

```
await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)
```

Am I missing something here?

---

The whole code:

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore

async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    print("Received the event: \"{}\" from the partition with ID: \"{}\"".format(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8'), partition_context.partition_id))
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string("AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING", "BLOB CONTAINER NAME")
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string("EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING", consumer_group="$Default", eventhub_name="EVENT HUB NAME", checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)
    async with client:
        await client.receive(on_event=on_event,  starting_position="-1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I can run the code successfully, and it only receive the new events. Can you please restart your receiver, and check it again. And also make sure using the latest version sdk.

Comment: the checkpoint information is stored as the metadata of a blob file (not the content of a blob file) which contains two key-value pairs: offset and sequencenumber, could you check whether the metadata of the blob is updated after you call update_checkpoint?

Comment: @IvanYang Yeah, updating the SDK solved the issue with processing the same elements multiple times. AdamLing thank you for the information, I was expecting the data to be stored in the blob file.

Comment: @Lubu I added an answer for that. If it's helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug in the old sdk.

Please try to install the latest version sdk: [azure-eventhub 5.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/) and [azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio 1.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio/).

I tested your code with these latest sdk, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the SDK solved the problem. Also @AdamLing clarified the metadata location for me in the comment.